# Using dplyr to aggregate data by year

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data in the following format:

| Year | Variable |
| --- | --- |
| 2010 | F |
| 2010 | N |
| 2012 | F |

And I want to format it as:

| Year | F | N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 1 | 1 |
| 2012 | 1 | 0 |

I know you can do this using dplyr pipes (%>%) but I just can't figure out the order of operations.

Thanks for any insight.